# Why is Google Play displaying the error "Can't install app"?

Tags: android, google-play

Probably this is not the best place to publish this question but it concerns developers so you will do me (and many of us) a favor if you don't remove this question:

Lately, many of my users are having problems installing my apps from Google Play. The download completes and installation starts, but Google Play finishes with this message:

> Can't install --App name--
>
> Try again, and if it still doesn't work, see common ways to fix the problem

Have you had the same issue?

I have asked Google but they do not provide much info and they are taking too long to fix it.

The devices that are displaying that message are from different brands and android versions. Like Samsung, Sony...

Those users also told me that they can download and install other apps from Play without problems. So, of course, they blame me, not Google Play.

I don't understand why they cannot install my apps.

I have been several weeks with this issue, so I have tested with them to clear Google Play cache, storage, reboot the device and all that.

It happens to many of my users (either to update or to start a fresh installation) but it works for most of the rest of the users. So, it is not something that happens to everybody, just to a few. Although those "few" are a lot.

Some users even told me that they had my app for years, and they had the error when trying to install the last update. Once they uninstall to do a fresh installation, then they cannot even continue.

Comment: Anything special with your app (used features, permissions, ...)? How do you distribute your app - as APK or app bundle? If you have contact with an user that has this problem and a bit of developer experience I would ask if he/she can sideload the app after download from web site. If that also fails it is the app and I would ask the user try to install it via `adb install` to see the error message.

Comment: I am not sure if those users will be able to do that. I can tell you that my app uses the same permissions and manifest than before the update but it has two changes. One of the new things is that I am using now the "app signing" option in Google Play Console and now the app is targeting SDK 32.

Comment: Google Play developers told me that the "app signing" option is not the problem

Comment: I upload the app to Google Play as app bundle

Comment: I am not sure if this is allowed by SO rules but if your users are not techy enough I would try to "croudsource" the problem: post the app package name and ask if some Android developer can try to install it on their test phones. May be one or two run into your problem and can help you by giving you details error message from logcat. Or if this is not allowed here you could do so on sea forums, I am sure there are enough Android devs who would help you.

Comment: Thanks Robert. What do you mean exactly with "sea forums"?

Comment: Sorry bad auto completion xda forums is what I wanted to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
One of the users that had the issue knew about computers and he showed me this log when installing:

```
03-10 18:26:01.393  1844  2241 W PackageManager: Package my.app.package attempting to redeclare permission android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES already owned by com.androidassistant.paid
03-10 18:26:01.404 13046 13046 E Finsky  : [2] ofn.onReceive(19): Error -505 while installing my.app.package: INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION: Package my.app.package attempting to redeclare permission android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES already owned by com.androidassistant.paid, ConflictingPackage: com.androidassistant.paid
03-10 18:26:01.414 13046 13046 W Finsky  : [2] khw.e(4): Installer::IT: Install failure of my.app.package (isid: ysr14RryQ9aB80XVw6H2BA): -505, Exception: n/a, ErrorMessage: INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION: Package my.app.package attempting to redeclare permission android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES already owned by com.androidassistant.paid, ConflictingPackage: com.androidassistant.paid
```

I removed the **QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES** permission from my Manifest file and the app can be installed now on all those devices that failed before. But I need that permission in my app. So now I would like to know why declaring that permission is having this problem on those devices. It sounds like a bug to me. I reported it to Google.

Comment: how to get Log of installing